# Combine 2 RadialGradient together in flutter Application

Tags: flutter

I am trying to apply two `RadialGradient`  in the top left and bottom right corners of the screen.
As far as I know I cannot do it using only 1 `RadialGradient`. So what I've tried to do, is to apply multiple.

I tried to use the `Stack` to place these both instances of `RadialGradient`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
  runApp(_MyApp());
}

class _MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: RadialGradient(
                radius: 0.8,
                center: Alignment.topLeft,
                colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(156, 135, 199, 1),
                  Colors.white,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              gradient: RadialGradient(
                radius: 0.8,
                center: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(156, 135, 199, 1),
                  Colors.white,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

But I got other result:
[image]

As you can see, there is no `RadialGradient` in the top left corner. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the color on both gradients from `Colors.white` to `Colors.white.withOpacity(0)`.

Right now you are obscuring the first gradient with the white background from the second gradient.

Comment: or use Colors.transparent

Comment: `Colors.transparent` is transparent black, not transparent white. Those are not the same thing and will yield different results.

Comment: Nice observation